# How is SARS-CoV-2 'deactivated' for some Covid vaccines (for example Covaxin)?

Tags: microbiology, virology, coronavirus, vaccination, covid

Some Covid vaccines like [Covaxin](https://www.bharatbiotech.com/covaxin.html) employ a 'Whole-Virion Inactivated Vero Cell'.

How is the virion 'deactivated' for the vaccine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Covaxin (BBV152), SARS-CoV-2 was inactivated by treatment with [β-propiolactone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-Propiolactone) [1]. β-propiolactone reacts with and modifies, among other things, nucleic acids, thus preventing their replication [2].

[1] [Yadav P, Ella R, Kumar S, et al. 2020. Remarkable immunogenicity and protective efficacy of BBV152, an inactivated SARS-CoV-2 vaccine in rhesus macaques. Preprint.](https://www.researchsquare.com/article/rs-65715/v1)

[2] [Perrin P, Morgeaux S. 1995. Inactivation of DNA by β-propiolactone. Biologicals 23(3):207-211.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1045105685700346?via%3Dihub)